# Suggestionsfor compositions for a short tabla solo for a beginner

Tags: tabla

I am an amateur tabla player and have been learning tabla on my own for the past two years.
I work full time so I have very little time to practice. That being said, I have learnt to play the theka of teen taal, a few forms of kherwa, theka of rupak, jhaptaal and ektaal.

Furthermore, I can play the following rela with fairly decent speed.

And I can play the following kaida with about 8 paltas(see image).
I want to prepare a short solo for my friends and work friends who are not familiar with Indian Classical Music, and was wondering if anyone had any suggestions for simple pieces that I could learn that I could add to the solo.
I also welcome any other suggestions.

[image: kaida]